# Bake a giant UV with multiples materials and textures tiled?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, uv, texture-baking

I'm working on this project:

[image]

I needed to bake the house structure, so I joined all objects, created smart uv project and started the bake.

It succeded, but the texture result wasn't correct:

[image]

The UV shrink

So seeing the UV (yes, it's a mess because of the object join) I think the problem is because of the scale:

[image]

If I create a bigger image texture, then the UV and UV canvas scales with it, so that's not really working

I'm pretty lost, I already tried packing islands (it still requires to scale UV outside limits so the tilling textures are displayied correctly and the bake keeps failing)

What could I do? Should I do a smallest bake? I tried searching how to increase the size of the UV canvas but I don't know if that would be correct or even possible

Thanks for your time

Comment: It is not possible to make 0-1 space bigger for baking. You will need to bake to new UV map which will have UV islands packed so that they don't intersect. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149917/blender-2-8-bake-multiple-textures-into-one

Comment: Right, I'm creating a new smart uv project. the problem is that the textures are too big (see the example in the bricks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot bake anything with overlapping UVs and outside of UV coordinates in the square (0,0),(1,1). You could create a separate UV map if you need to have different UV maps for other textures:

[image]

It's fine to scale other UV maps than the one used for baking, but you could also use a vector mapping node.

You would need to connect the right UV maps to the image node you are baking to and to other textures as well:

[image]

All UVs intended for baking need to be inside the square and not overlapping like this:

[image]

This defines where the information from the bake is going to be saved in the baked image so if you have overlapping UVs you have places on the image where Blender would need to save information from multiple places of the 3d object so that cannot work.

Comment: So, this is the best I could get for example of the bricks? [image](https://imgur.com/icRc0dK) (ignore the overlapping, just testing)  Should I resize the texture outside blender to get the desired result?

Comment: You should use a different UV map for the bricks(and other things) and do whatever you want with it and then make another UV map for all the geometry of the mesh just for the baking.

Comment: I understand but even with a new UV, the texture isn't displaying correctly because the UV square is too small. If the UV square can't be resized, then the trouble is with the texture, Am I right? (If the bricks were smaller, then the tiled would look correct). If it's not a problem with the texture, maybe I can't do this bake how I'm thinking

Comment: I just added to the question, for clarification, that I created a new UV project before the bake (so the trouble is 100% because of how the bricks, and other textures scales)

Comment: It's fine to scale other UV maps than the one used for baking, or use a vector mapping node.

Comment: Nice one!! "Use a vector mapping node" was the actual solution! Do you want to add it to your answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: Sure. Added it.