# Creating a Single Image Texture Bake From A Complex Object - Broken Textures Result in 2.9

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I'm very very hilariously new to Blender but am trying to suss out a specific project.  I have a complex object created from several different objects, each of which has its own texture image, each texture image made up of 3-5 layered textures, that I want to combine into a single texture image so I can import it into Tabletop Simulator.

I've spent several days stumbling from tutorial to tutorial to tutorial but I cannot for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

This is the model with the final surface texture I want to bake:

[image]

This is the tutorial I've had the most success with:

[Blender 2.8 Bake multiple textures into one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149917/blender-2-8-bake-multiple-textures-into-one)

Here's my bake result:

[image]

Which looks broken in my shading tab.

[image]

Yet somehow even worse in TTS.

[image]

I've tried baking just the Diffuse, as well as changing the Max Ray Distance from 0 to .5, and this is the best result I've gotten yet.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How does it look in rendered view before baking?

Comment: I don't know, none of the tutorials ever mentioned that

Comment: Rendering image via f12 results in a blank image

Comment: Am I supposed to be rendering first?

Comment: No, you don't have to render first, but it can be a good way to check for problems. You can check in the viewport by clicking the rightmost sphere in the upper right of the 3D view. Also, there is a lot of magenta which is usually caused by a missing texture.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried checking face's normals? if they are inverted, on TTS they might not appear correctly. It is usually an easy fix.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)