# Baking not working for complex material

Tags: materials, texture-baking

I'm currently working on baking the texture of a tower. I followed the steps highlighted in this other answer [Blender 2.8 Bake multiple textures into one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149917/blender-2-8-bake-multiple-textures-into-one) but at the moment of baking of the final object with the starting texture a strange thing happens. For the bricks texture the baking operation seems to work, but for the other 2 materials it seems not to grasp colors and their distribution. In one case the system understands only the noise texture of a portion of the material. For the second case it does not understand the material at all leaving me with a black result.
The two problematic materials are respectively:

- black and white image texture use as "fac" between two different shaders, one a mixture of gray and white thanks to a color ramp (and a noise texture as Fac), the other a mixture between an image and white thanks to a color ramp (again with a noise texture as Fac).
- A simple material with a color ramp between gray and white and a noise texture as Fac

[image: Image of wrong baking result]

[[image: Starting tower2]

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your problem but first thing, put a Diffuse between your ColorRamp and your Output

Comment: The problem is that the baking of the texture in the second image results in the first image and only the bricks part is maintained.

Comment: have you tried to put a Diffuse? If it still doesn't work please pack your images (important) and share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: yes, but the situation does not change, if possible it even worsened. Today I have not much time. Later I will try other possibilities, if they don't work I will share my images. Thank you!

Comment: @moonboots I tried again with the diffuse and not it works, thank you a lot! Probably yesterday I was making a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a *Diffuse* node between your *ColorRamp* and your *Output*, otherwise it acts like an *Emission* and you won't be able to bake the material.